# UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.username error in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

For some unknown reasons, I am facing that error

I have searched for some of the possible errors but those I have tried doesn't work

I tried  `user = form.save(commit=False)` maybe it would work but no positive result

Error log:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/register-result

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'apps.accounts',
 'apps.result']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'apps.result.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.username) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\apps\accounts\views.py", line 32, in register_school
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 146, in create_user
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 140, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 935, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\resultLab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/register-result
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.username
```

Views:

```
def register_school(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SchoolRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned = form.cleaned_data
        username = cleaned['username']
        password = cleaned['password']
        email = cleaned['email']
        school_name = cleaned['school_name']
        address = cleaned['address']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
        user.usertype = 'result'
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        school = School(user=user,
                        name=school_name,
                        address=address,
                        )
        school.save()
        return redirect(reverse('registration-complete', kwargs={'username': username}))
else:
    form = SchoolRegistrationForm
    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

Form:

```
class SchoolRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_second = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email Address')
    school_name = forms.CharField(label='School Name')
    address = forms.CharField(label='Office Address')
```

Comment: are those fields in `SchoolRegistrationForm` form based on your `User` model ? do you have a custom `User`?

Comment: The error simply says that the `username` you typed in already exists in the database. Also, `form.save(commit=False)` would not work anyway since the `form` is not a `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error simply says that the `username` you typed in already exists in the database. To solve this add form validation for the field `username` in `SchoolRegistrationForm`. Also, `form.save(commit=False)` would not work anyway since the form is not a `ModelForm`.

Only model based forms `ModelForm` have a built-in [save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). For forms based on `Form`, you have to create a modal object and save that instance.

```py
def register_school(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SchoolRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned = form.cleaned_data

            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#creating-users
            username = cleaned['username']
            password = cleaned['password']
            email = cleaned['email']
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password
                )
            user.usertype = 'result'
            user.save()

            # create model instance and save()
            school_name = cleaned['school_name']
            address = cleaned['address']
            school = School(
                user=user,
                name=school_name,
                address=address,
                )
            school.save()
            return redirect(reverse('registration-complete', kwargs={'username': username}))     
    else:
        form = SchoolRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

Add validation to the `username` field in `SchoolRegistrationForm` form. This will check if the username already exists and raise a validation error in the form rather than a modal error while creating the `User` in views.

```py
# forms.py
# imports
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SchoolRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username')
    # other fields

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute
    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user_model = get_user_model()
        if user_model.objects.filter(username=data).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Username already exists")

        # Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data, even if
        # this method didn't change it.
        return data
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir
your solution worked just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

From the flow of your code this might be the problem:

```
# first you call user variable
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
# set uset attribute
user.usertype = 'result'
# you override `user` variable
user = form.save(commit=False)
# now trying to save the form so result in trying to create another record with the same data
user.save()

# failed because username have unique constrain
```

You don't need to set user = form.save(commit=False) because i don't see anywhere else you calling the form with `user` variable